# how to find the index of many values from a list

Tags: python, arraylist

I have a list of values with a length of 100 and I want to know how can I get their index in a list in python.
For example:

```
target_values = [0,0.001,0.002,0.003,..., 0.01]
len(target_values) = 100
list = [0,0.0005,0.001, 0.0015, 0.002,...., 0.1]
len(list) = 1747
Output_index = [0,2,4,..., n]
len(Output_index) = 100 #should be 100
```

Is there any way to find it?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some code you've written and we can help guide you to a solution

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the target values and find them in the large list using `index()`

```py
target_values = [0,0.001,0.002,0.003,..., 0.01]
large_list = [0,0.0005,0.001, 0.0015, 0.002,...., 0.1]
output_index = []
for value in target_values:
  output_index.append(large_list.index(value))
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`index()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html#array.array.index) function does that. Note that it may not work well if you have duplicate items in the list.

Don't use `list` as a variable name. It will shadow the type `list`.

```py
target_values = [0,0.001,0.002,0.003,..., 0.01]
larger_list = [0,0.0005,0.001, 0.0015, 0.002,...., 0.1]
Output_index = []
for value in target_values:
    try:
        Output_index.append(larger_list.index(value))
    except ValueError:
        # value not found in larger list, handle it
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar answer to @Victor, but with list comprehension and returns `None` just in case the target value is not in the list.

```
target_values = [0,0.001,0.002, 0.003, 0.01]
large_list = [0,0.0005,0.001, 0.0015, 0.002, 0.1]

output_index = [large_list.index(target_value) 
                if target_value in large_list 
                else None 
                for target_value in target_values]

print(output_index)
```

Answer (score 0):

One efficient way is to loop a filtered list. Meaning you should use the `filter()` method to filter lists. That way the for loop will only loop sure values but not unnecessary values. You don't even have to worry about `value` or `index` errors because you are only looping values that you are interested in.

```py
target_values = [0,0.001,0.002,0.003,..., 0.01]
lst = [0,0.0005,0.001, 0.0015, 0.002,..., 0.1]

output_index = [lst.index(value) for value in filter(lambda x: x in lst, target_values)]
print(output_index)
```